# Calling a method from a class inside a static method in another class. TYPESCRIPT

Tags: typescript

Hi im developing an api using express, objection and knex and encounter the following problem.

Im trying to call a method from a class inside a static method in another class, i dont understand why i cant do this. Any help is welcome.

CODE:

```
class UserService {
    public async getUserByEmail(email: string) {
        //fun stuff
    }
}

class AuthController {
    public userService: UserService;

    constructor(_userService: UserService) {
        this.userService = _userService;
    }
    
    static async login(req: Request, res: Response) {
        //Here i CANT call this.userService.getUserByEmail()
    }

    async register(req: Request, res: Response) {
        this.userService.getUserByEmail();
        
        //Here i CAN call the method from userService
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: You can't access instance properties (anything that must be qualified with `this`) from inside a static context, the other way is fine though. Either remove the static keyword or make the thing you are trying to access static as well

Comment: Adding to what @Teedeez said, the reason is that `this` inside a class method is not the `this` of the instance. ES6 classes have prototypes under the hood.

Comment: because in static methods/functions you don't have access to this( instance of class) due to the fact that it's not initiated yet. in javascript's world you can find `bind`, `call` and `apply` useful for this situations. It means you have to bind your static function to an instance of UserService .
if you use something like inversifiy you can use its `lazyInject` utils to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 1):

Statics in any class means they can be used without initiating new object so in static methods/functions you don't have access to `this`(instance of class) due to the fact that it's not initiated yet.

In javascript's world you can find `bind`, `call` and `apply` useful for this situations. It means you have to bind your static function to an instance of `UserService`.

If you use something like inversifiy to control your injections you can use its `lazyInject` utils to achieve this functionality.